# Is there a way to post an image post from my Tumblr blog to my Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, tumblr, if-this-then-that

Is there an automated way to post an image post from my Tumblr blog to my Facebook wall? I've been looking at using IFTTT, which I've used before in the past for automated tasks like this, but I couldn't seem to find anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me this recipe should do what you want:

### Trigger:

[Tumblr](https://ifttt.com/tumblr) channel, [New photo post](https://ifttt.com/channels/tumblr/triggers/36-new-photo-post) trigger

Available Ingredients:

You'll want `PhotoFullUrl` or `PhotoThumbUrl` or possibly even `Url`, depending on what you want to post. Probably also want to use `Caption` and or `Tags`.

### Action:

[Facebook](https://ifttt.com/facebook) channel

You probably want to use "Upload a photo from URL" action, but possibly "Create a link post" and use the URL from your Tumblr post. It all depends on how you want it to appear. ("Create status message" only allows for plain text.)

[This recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/208188-upload-tumblr-photo-post-to-facebook-album) is probably enough to get you started. There are others: [search for recipes that use Tumblr and Facebook](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?ac=false&page=2&q=tumblr+facebook).

Comment: Thanks @Al E. i ended up creating my own recipe with what you set out above which can be viewed here : https://ifttt.com/recipes/318673-post-image-post-from-tumblr-to-facebook-page